# Error with dependencies when syncing Gradle

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebaseui

I have used firebase as a backend to my application and, as a consequence, I am using firebase auth with firebase UI for authentication but I'm facing an error:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // firebaes dependancies.
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:25.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/AndroidStudioProjects/android-client/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

and

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/AndroidStudioProjects/android-client/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

and

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/AndroidStudioProjects/android-client/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I went aside with some answers to similar questions in this forum and went to SDK Manager> SDK Tools > Uppdate repositories. But it did not work!!

Any Ideas where this error is coming from?? I am guessing it is because of the android SDK version, Is that a correct guess?

***Edit:*** I am putting %USERPROFILE% instead of my user folder name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You are trying to download an unexisting repo. Where did you get the `25.4.0` versioning from? Anyhow. if you are targetting Nougat you should replace all `25.4.0` to `25.3.1'`

Also, dont use `26.+`. It's highly discouraged as Android Studio itself will tell you. There's no need to do such a thing.

Comment: I have found a solution but I do not know if it is correct. I just reinstalled Google repository packages again and add google maven dependencies then adb kill-server and start-server. The problem seems to be resolved but I am not sure whether it is temporarily or permanently resolved.

Comment: Good. But at least remove the `26.+` thing. It will save you headaches. Trust me.

Comment: I have removed all of these packages with 26.+ since I downloaded the whole google repository. I am not sure of what I am doing, but the code is executed fine.

Comment: Nice. I don't need it, but for future references, make sure you upvote/mark answers as correct when someone helps you. Otherwise you will be seen as a *help vampire* and you will likely not be helped in the future.

Comment: Thanks for that generous help, time and effort. I really appreciate it Mr @Chisko
^_^

Comment: I already have made an upvote but it is not shown to the public regarding the forum policies.